# SubmitCompleteHandler GWT FormPanel never trigger

Tags: django, gwt, file-upload

This problem probably has been discussed, but this one is slightly different.

I'm using GWT FormPanel + FileUpload widget to upload a file. My backend is python-django.

My problem is, the GWT FormPanel never trigger the SubmitCompleteHandler event. And on the django log, I can see "Broken pipe", which probably indicates that the other end (browser) closed the connection.

I've found some link indicates browser quirks, but I'm still not sure how to get around this issue. Any insights?

Thanks, KOkon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh..

Found that the FormPanel should not be hidden while the upload process is ongoing.
By deferring the hide() until the upload completed, I don't get the error anymore.